# How I can run iOS app twice on MacOS Apple Silicon(M1)?

Tags: ios, apple-silicon

I am engaged in the development and testing of iOS applications, there was a need to run two instances of the application at the same time. Can anyone suggest a way how to do it?

- I tried to copy the app file and run the copy, but it foreground the current application
- I also tried to run through the terminal using the command open with flag n, it will crash
- When you try to open it through the terminal as a different user, the application crashes too.

Comment: Are you running this as a macOS app or through the iOS simullator? - If doing professionally just use one of your test phones etc - you have several of the different types to make sure you app runs don't you?

Comment: I don't have an ARM mac, but have you tried running the binary itself through terminal? Typing `/path/to/AppName.app/Contents/iOS(?)/AppName`

Answer (score 1):

On an iOS device, an app can never run simultaneously with itself (unlike macOS, for which you already know the `open- n` command). It's not unreasonable to expect a virtual iOS environment on your M1 Mac doesn't support this either. So I think your test case

> there was a need to run two instances of the application at the same time

is a bit flawed. If you need to test what happens when a user uses the application (with the same Apple ID) simultaneously on two different devices, you have to adapt your test case to this as well. Various options (but I don't know if they're feasible for you):

- use an iPhone
- use a Mac
- use Xcode's iOS simulator
- use virtualization software to simulate another macOS instance inside your Mac