# Opening multiple instances of an iOS app on macOS with M2 Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, ios, terminal, applications, apple-silicon

I'm using an M2 Macbook Pro to open iOS apps (Any Mac with Apple silicon allows this), but I'm trying to open multiple instances of the application. However, there's no way to do this in the UI.

Trying to open a new instance using terminal (`open -n "/Users/user/Desktop/AppName.app"`) gives me an error code if there is already an instance of the app open: `_LSOpenURLsWithCompletionHandler() failed with error -10670`.

Also, I tried duplicating and renaming the app to run a duplicated version, but doing that redirects to the original app. I also tried renaming the original application within the package contents folder and wrapper folder. Still, when I try to open the duplicated app, I get told: `You can't open the application "AppName.app" because it may be damaged or incomplete`.

Finally, I tried again on terminal to open another instance of the app from another user (`sudo -u user2 open -n "/Applications/AppName.app`), but it gave me the same error code: `_LSOpenURLsWithCompletionHandler() failed with error -10670`.

I'm not really sure where to go from here, and would definitely appreciate any insight or advice.

Comment: This may be risky anyway. Even if you manage to run the app twice, they may share preferences, local storages etc which will lead to data corruption.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by running more than one instance? Perhaps there's another way?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433594/how-i-can-run-ios-app-twice-on-macos-apple-siliconm1